# Request header field sentry-trace is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response

Tags: next.js, keycloak, sentry

I'm developing a Frontend using NextJS and Keycloak for auth-purpose. After adding Sentry, I'm facing this issue here, where the `token` endpoint of Keycloak is returning an error; So I can log in.

I've tried many things:

- Change the web-origin config of Keycloak, which (obviously) doesn't change or solves the problem
- Play with the Sentry client config, without success, because the `denyUrls` property still make the Sentry SDK send the `sentry-trace` into the request.

Now I don't have any more Idea, so I coming here for more help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So after some investigations, I came across this `tracingOrigins` property that can be set using integrations like this:

```js
integrations: [
    new (Sentry.Integrations as any).BrowserTracing({
        tracingOrigins: [
            process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_URL,
            process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BACKEND_URL,
            process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_MATOMO_URL,
        ],
    }),
],
```

This config is done inside the `sentry.client.config.ts` file. The downside is that, urls which are not included there, are simply not tracked.

Comment: For future readers of this question, this is documented here: https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/javascript/guides/nextjs/performance/instrumentation/automatic-instrumentation/#tracingorigins

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, Keycloak has [hardcoded list of allowed headers](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/36da2d20e97a10821c7305881d3ffa343b5ad001/services/src/main/java/org/keycloak/services/resources/Cors.java#L44), so you can't configure Keycloak for `sentry-trace` header.

You can have some non ideal work arounds:

- don't use sentry
- compile own hacked Keycloak version, where you allow that header
- add reverse proxy in front of Keycloak, which will add `sentry-trace` header to allowed headers
- ...

Comment: I already known that Keycloak hardcoded a list of allowed headers, but to this extends it's frustrating. So I went with the third option here - using a reverse Proxy. I opted for nginx.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this issue on a nextJs application by adding the following header to the static sourcemap response.
`'Access-Control-Allow-Headers'` on `next.config.js`

```js
const CONFIG = {
  headers: () => [
    {
      source: "/_next/:path*",
      headers: [
        { key: "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", value: SHOP_ORIGIN },
        { key: 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers', value: '*' },
      ],
    },
  ],
}
```